PgAdmin 4 Port Forwarding for SSH Tunnel
With e.g. DBeaver it's easy to setup port forwarding for a ssh tunnel (remote host + port and local host + port in SSH Tunnel tab). In PgAdmin 4 I don't see such an option. I didn't find any hint with Google or within the PgAdmin docs. How to setup the different ports in PgAdmin? It's possible?
